# Reference external JS method in Chart.js callback using Chartjs.ror

Tags: javascript, chart.js, ruby-on-rails-6

I am building a Ruby on Rails app and am integrating Chart.js via chartjs.ror.  I've defined a my chart's options similar to this:

```
@options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      callback: "function(value, index, values) {return '$' + number_format(value);}"
                  }
               }]
    }
}
```

I have a JS method called number_format(), but everywhere I put it I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: number_format is not defined
```

Where do I put javascript methods where they will be picked up by `Chart.js`, specifically when using the Ruby `chartjs-ror` gem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/airblade/chartjs-ror#sample-output), `chartjs-ror` outputs a script tag on your page.

Make sure `number_format` is defined on the page before the output of the chartjs-ror gem, e.g. at the top of the page, before your charts.